# Swift dot notation efficiency

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift, say I'm using self.frame in UIView at several places. Is it more efficient to store self.frame in a variable and use the variable at multiple places? Is there any difference on performance or otherwise?

Comment: "self" is mostly implicit in Swift, so you can just use frame instead of self.frame. In any case, I don't think it would make any difference to assign self.frame to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.frame` is a *property*. A property is an abstraction where what happens when you read from or write to it is abstracted away from the caller.

The `.frame` here is a property of the Objective-C class `UIView`, and in Objective-C, properties are simply a pair of methods (a getter-setter pair). What happens inside those methods is unknown to the caller. It could read/write from an instance variable (i.e. synthesized); or it can compute it from other sources. In fact, the documentation for `UIView` suggests that `.frame` is actually computed from `.bounds` and `.center`, rather than stored directly. But how it is actually implemented is irrelevant, because any caller must assume that a property can be computed.

This is not specific to Objective-C classes. The same thing is true in pure-Swift classes. A caller cannot assume that a property is stored, unless it is `final`. A stored property can still be overridden by a computed property in a subclass. Therefore, in general, when accessing a non-`final` property, the compiler must assume that it could potentially be computed.

Two accesses of a computed property cannot be ever assumed to produce the same result, no matter how short the intervening code is. (I can have a computed property that returns the system time, for example.) Plus, a computed property can have side effects. Therefore, a computer cannot freely change the number of times a property is accessed (similar to method calls). So it will access the property twice if you write the dot notation twice; whereas if you do it only once and save it in a variable, it only has to do it once. Therefore, accessing it once and storing it in a variable can be more efficient, if only slightly.

Comment: Thanks @newacct That was precisely the motivation behind the question. Thanks for laying it out so clearly.

Answer (score 4):

Compilers are remarkably good at finding this type of local optimization nowadays, so it is just an optimization hint now. Every level of indirection will *probably* incur some type of runtime penalty, but with a good compiler it may be hard to tell. So to be sure you would have to run a benchmark *in context*, as otherwise the optimization might just have been found anyway.

In the type of compiled language that Swift is I would expect a minimal gain if any, so I would probably not base my decision on this local optimization. Try to look at your code and ask yourself which version looks more clear. For such a simple thing as a single level of variable dereference I think this matters more than the run time. If you do this *really* often in some kind of closed loop there might be a measurable difference, but you should not optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

What's efficient is to store it into a `let` variable and reference it from there. But you can't do that if it's going to change. In that case, probably nothing is more efficient than just fetching it each time. You certainly can't store it in *any* variable if it *is* going to change, because what you're storing is a *copy* (because it's a struct, and structs are value types); the value in your variable will not change when the view's frame changes, so you'll end up getting the wrong answer.

However, what's *really* efficient is ***not to optimize prematurely***. You are wasting your time and energy and everyone else's on this nonsense. Just write your program. If it's slow, then use Instruments to find out why.

Comment: Thanks matt! I'm new to Swift – please excuse my nonsense.

Comment: Not optimizing prematurely is a general principle. Don't sweat the small stuff, especially when you don't even know if it is stuff at all. That has nothing to do with Swift (although the fact that a struct is copied on assignment in Swift could be important, because it might make assigning a frame to a variable downright counterproductive).

Answer (score 0):

`self.frame.size.width` and other frame attributes are all variables. There are no calculation to get that data so it won't change the performance to store it on another variable or use them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Test it yourself:

- run your app with `self.frame`
- run your app with a custom variable.
- check if you can tell any difference in the performance.

If you can't tell a difference, then they're both the same. If you can tell the difference then use the one that's faster.

I would not assume `self.frame` is faster or slower. It could be faster or slower, it depends what the complier does.

Also make sure you do your testing with the compiler set to production build settings, not debug build settings. This is exactly the area where a debug build and a production build could be the opposite (I.E. one could be faster in production, the other could be faster in a debug build).

If I had to make an educated guess, I would say `self.frame` is faster. Also, `self.frame` will use less RAM which is probably more important than speed. But I could be wrong on both counts.